# Menu/Application Launchers Missing in 15.10

Tags: unity, unity-dash, cinnamon, launcher

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 and added Cinnamon (kranich package), and some of the Applications I've installed, (Steam, Virtualbox etc) are missing their launchers, in both Unity and Cinnamon.

Alt-f2 launches them just fine, but I'd like to just be able to launch them using the Meta Key or pin the Launchers to my desktop. Any help would be appreciated.